# How to get the value entered in the Username field of sdLogonInformation dialog and use in another rul file

Tags: installscript, installscript-msi

I am using Installscript-MSI project project.

For getting username and password from the user, I am using sdLogonUserInformation dialog. For example username and password stored in the variables szUser, szPassword respectively. Now I want to use this variable in another rul file to insert it into a config file.

Please suggest me the code to archive this...

Installscript

```
  szTitle = "";
  szMsg = "";
  svUser = "";
  svPassword = "";
  //{{IS_SCRIPT_TAG(EnterLoginInfo)
  nResult = SdLogonUserInformation(szTitle, szMsg, svUser, svPassword);
```

want to use variables svUser, svPassword in another rul file

Answer (score 0):

Just Declare Username and password variables as global(May be in setup.rul). so you can access them from all the rul scripts included in your project.